# How to pass the data as object in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I want to receive the value thought iterator, when I use

```
$('#someModal').find('input[name=nameProBangHHModal]').val(data[0].TenNhanQuyCach);
```

it works as expected.

But when I use an iterator, the return shows `[object Object].TenNhanQuyCach` - not the data returned.

I try to search for other topic but I'm stuck on this. How to get the data returned in `array[data[0]]` with the value from the iterator method?

Thank you for your time!

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'someurl to retrive data',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id:id},
            success: function(data,status) {
                var tenCot = ['nameProBangHHModal','valueBangHHModal',];
                var tenCotTrongCsdl = ['TenNhanQuyCach','DonViTinh',];
                console.log(tenCotTrongCsdl[0]);
                for (i=0;i <= tenCot.length - 1;i++) {
                    $('#someModal').find('input[name="' + tenCot[i] + '"]').val(data[0]+'.'+tenCotTrongCsdl[i]');
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i find out the answer after search topic for array: this one: [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/11922384#11922384).
and find out that need to use [] for variable, not the ".".
this one work for me:

```
$('#someModal').find('input[name="' + tenCot[i] + '"]').val(data[0][tenCotTrongCsdl[i]]);
```